# allocating memory for structure pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Why is it that when we declare a structure pointer we need to allocate memory

```
struct A{
///
};
int main(void)
{
    struct A *var=(struct A*)malloc(sizeof(struct A));
//
//
}
```

but when we declare a structure variable we do not need to allocate any memory?

```
struct A var;
```

Comment: One way or another, if you want to use a pointer to a structure, you need it to point to something valid. That something could be dynamic (as you show in the first example), but it could easily be automatic as well (`struct A var, *pvar = &var;`). A good C book and/or tutorial covers pointer usage, dynamic allocation, etc. It's worth the investment of time to read more about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true for any pointers, not just pointers to structures. The reason being, when you declare a variable (of type int, char or the type of some struct A), you tell the compiler to create a new variable/instance. So, the compiler automatically allocates memory for that variable. But when you are declaring a pointer to some int or some struct A, you are essentially telling the compiler that you need a reference to some variable, not an a new variable of that type entirely. To illustrate this:

```c
struct A{};
int a,b; // New variable a and b
struct A c,d; // New variables c,d of type struct A

// Now take a look at this:

int *px;
px = &a; // px referencing to a, no new int variable created;
px = &b; // px referencing to b, no new int variable created;

struct A* py;
py = &c; // py referencing to c, no new struct A variable created;
py = &d; // py referencing to d, no new struct A variable created;
```

Now, if you just declare a pointer A* p, here p is not referencing to anything. So, if you want p to refer to a new instance of struct A, you have to write explicitly:

```
c
p = (struct A*)malloc(sizeof(struct A));
```

Comment: The examples here are C++ (missing `struct` and the `new` operator).

Comment: `int *` and `A *` will also take memory in the stack (barring optimizations). Further, you shouldn't use `malloc` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

- `struct A var` declares a variable `var` on stack area of main memory with internal structure as declared in the `struct A`.
- `struct A * var` also declares a variable `var` on stack area of main memory but the `var` is a pointer now, and as you may know, a pointer in C is used to store address of a variable, so the `var` need to know what is the address, the statment `(struct A*)malloc(sizeof(struct A));` gives you the address.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily *have* to allocate memory when declaring a pointer (it can point to any existing object of the same type), but in order to use a pointer without causing undefined behavior, it has to point to an object of that type.  Since pointers are used extensively in data structures, it is more often than not that allocated objects are the ones most commonly pointed to, which is why it seems like you have to allocate memory.